# How to count the number of external tags only (XML)?

Tags: java

I need to count the quantity of external objects tags only (Here there are only 2). XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_201" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">

<object class="com.labs.crud.classes.Order">
  <void property="id">
   <int>1</int>
  </void>
  <object>
  ...
  </object>
</object>

<object class="com.labs.crud.classes.Order">
  <void property="id">
   <int>2</int>
  </void>
  <object>
  ...
  </object>
</object>

</java>
```

Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(path);
document. ...What`s next?

Comment: what are external objects? do you mean the ones directly under the root element?

Comment: Yes. First children under root. Two <object class="com.labs.crud.classes.Order">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after you parse the document, you follow the DOM api

```
NodeList list = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
IntStream.range(0, list.getLength())
         .filter(i -> list.item(i).getNodeName().equals("object"))
         .forEach(i -> System.out.println(list.item(i).getNodeName()));
```

what ever you need to take from the object node, use the [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) api to get it